# powershell complicated regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been stuck trying to write a regular expression that matches the following condition. Basically, I have a text file that contains several text lines (composed of words and digits). For example:

> Some_text Number 45 Some_text ptrn: anchor Some_text Number 22 Some_text

What I need is to return “45” (or any other digits after word “Number”), but only in case that in the line was found “ptrn: anchor”. Again, if the pattern “ptrn: anchor” has been found in some line, the script should **look back** all along the line until it gets **first** word “Number” and then output the digits beside it.

I'm not so good at regular expressions and very appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't use a single regular expression for this. It almost certainly isn't worth it. Check for `ptrn: anchor` first and then grab any numbers from your (now much simpler) regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

`"Number\s*(\d+).*ptrn: anchor"`

Note that if there are multiple numbers before `ptrn: anchor` in a single line, the first one will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. If I use the pattern it gives me not only “45” but all text between “Number “ and  “ptrn: anchor “. In my example its output
> “Number 45 Some_text ptrn: anchor”
The code:
>$arr = @()
>$path = "C:\Text.txt"
>$pattern = "Number\s*(\d+).*ptrn: anchor"
>
>Get-Content $path | Foreach {if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) {
>           $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)
>            }
>        }
>$arr | Foreach {$_.Value}

Comment: You should use `$matches[1]` instead of `$matches[0]`, because there is a round-bracketed section that'll capture the 45.

Comment: If someone wants my final code: $path = "C:\Text.txt"
$pattern = "Number\s*(\d+).*ptrn: anchor"
select-string -path $path -pattern $pattern | % {$_ -match $p > $null; $matches[1]}

Comment: If that helped, please press a "tick" at the left of the answer that helped you most. This gives you reputation as a loyal user.